# Saving list of items to firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My OrderModel:

```
public class OrderModel {
    private String itemName;
    private String orderUnit;
    private long itemId;
    private double amountAsPerTheQuantity;
    private double orderQuantity;
    private double rateOfItemPrice;


    public OrderModel() {
        //required Empty constructor for Firebase
    }


    public OrderModel(String itemName, long itemId, double rateOfItemPrice, double amountAsPerTheQuantity, double orderQuantity) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.amountAsPerTheQuantity = amountAsPerTheQuantity;
        this.rateOfItemPrice = rateOfItemPrice;
        this.orderQuantity = orderQuantity;
    }

    // ... setters and getters
}
```

My Repository Class:

```
public void insertNewOrder( List<OrderModel> orderModelList ) {

    databaseReference = databaseReference.child("DeliveryOrders");
    String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    databaseReference.child(key).setValue(orderModelList);
```

I am getting an error while I try to save a List of custom objects to firebase at once... the error that I am getting is:

> Found a conflicting setters with name: setItemId (conflicts with
> setItemId defined on com.sabirali.myorder.Models.OrderModel)

and this line number points to the method in the Repository Class which takes this list as an argument(parameter).
This custom POJO/Model class has
a field called itemId and also is there its setter and getter...

Please someone help me ! I am stuck for days now, almost more than a week but cannot figure out a way . please help me .
Please someone help me . I am stuck for almost 10 days now !

Comment: "I am getting an error while I try to save a List of custom objects to firebase" -> "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Try to annotate your fields with `@Exclude`